# Extract KeyCode from KeyData

Tags: c#, .net, input, key

How can I extract the KeyCode flag (a `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` value without modifiers) itself from a `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` value?

Let's say the `Keys` has the flags `Keys.Control`, `Keys.Shift` and `Keys.A`. I want to extract the `Keys.A` flag, but the `Keys`´s flags (including modifiers) are variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Keys enum already has a mask for that, its name will not surprise you:

```
  Keys code = keyData & Keys.KeyCode;
```

Its underlying value is 0xffff, effectively masking off the modifier state bits.  A similar mask value is available to isolate the modifiers bits, its is Keys.Modifiers (0xffff0000).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
Keys excludeModifier = yourKey & ~Keys.Control & ~Keys.Shift & ~Keys.Alt;
```